# Is the empty relation invertible?

Tags: relations

$A$ is a nonempty set. The empty relation $\emptyset$ is a relation on $A$.
Is the relation $R=\emptyset$ invertible in $(R(A),\circ)$?

I think no because there is no $S\in R(A)$ such that $\emptyset\circ S = I$, the identity relation.

If $A$ is an empty set??

Thank you.

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Comment: I guess a more threshold problem is how you define the *identity* relation on the empty set.

Comment: Is it true that for each $(x,y)\in R$, $(y,x)\in R$?

Comment: That's right. $\emptyset\circ S=\emptyset\neq I$, when $A\neq\emptyset$. On the other hand, for $A=\emptyset$, then $I=\emptyset$. In this case $\emptyset=\emptyset^T=\emptyset^{-1}$.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by “invertible,” which depends (hopefully) on some motivating problem context.  Can you add any such context to your question?

Comment: @user3716267 [Inverse relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation#Inverses)

Comment: @user85667 That’s probably  not what’s meant by “invertible” here. Every relation has an inverse, but not every relation is invertible.

Comment: @BrianO Every relation has a transpose, not an inverse.

Comment: @user85667 Call it what you will. “Inverse” as the name for the reverse relation is quite old & well-attested but, agreed, it’s misleading in that it isn’t  an inverse in the algebraic sense. If $R$ is a function then nobody calls $R^{-1}$ its *transpose*.

Comment: @BrianO You: "That's probably not what's meant by invertible here".  Second line of the question: "I think no because there is no S∈R(A) such that ∅∘S=I, the identity relation." Just don't waste my time.

Comment: @user85667 It’ll be a pleasure to never interact  with you again. Good luck with that winning personality.

Comment: @BrianO LOL! Yet, you @ me again.